# Qt HTML Subset -- possible undocumented limitation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a little bit of hand-coded HTML inside """ marks in the Python code below. It works fine in Chrome but the background color is unexpected when I show it in a PyQT text browser.

[image: output in Chrome]

[image]

The "more pink" line does not have a pink background.

As I read https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTextBrowser.html it seems that all of the features I am using are listed as covered. But something is still gang agley.

What HTML would achieve the pink background extending over two lines in a Text Browser widget?

Here is the code for this example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(364, 284)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(
            """
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
            <html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" />
            </head>
            <body style=" font-family:'.SF NS Text'; font-size:13pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
                <p>preliminary text</p>
                <div style = " -qt-block-indent:1;  font-style:italic;  background-color:#fff5f5;  font-style:italic;">
                    background pink
                    <p>more pink</p>
                </div>

                <p> Non pink <\p>
            </body></html>
            """
        )
        self.retranslateUi(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have included Qt as well as PyQt as tags because I think the issue would be the same in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextBrowser` is based on `QTextDocument` that only supports a [limited subset of HTML4](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) unlike Google Chrome supports HTML5 so you can see the differences. If you want to have a behavior similar to Google Chrome then use `QWebEngineView` (`pip install pyqtwebengine`):

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    html ="""
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
        <html>
            <head>
            <meta name="qrichtext" content="1" />
            </head>
            <body style=" font-family:'.SF NS Text'; font-size:13pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
                <p>preliminary text</p>
                <div style = " -qt-block-indent:1;  font-style:italic;  background-color:#fff5f5;  font-style:italic;">
                    background pink
                    <p>more pink</p>
                </div>
                <p> Non pink </p>
            </body>
        </html>
            """

    browser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
    browser.setHtml(html)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    view.setHtml(html)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(browser, stretch=1)
    lay.addWidget(view, stretch=1)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]
<sup>(On the left is the QTextBrowser and on the right the QWebEngineView)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This is a situation where QTextBrowser implements HTML4's <DIV> incorrectly. But I see the wisdom in just going to QWebEngineView.